# Returning blank rows when a specific column is used

Tags: powerbi, dax, relationship, powerbi-desktop

I seem to be having some issues with my data model as it is bringing back blank rows meaning that the relationship is invalid, so it is showing the rows that don't basically exist or cannot be matched.

**With Branch Type Column**

[image]

**Without Branch Type Column**

[image]

**Data Model:**

[image]

I know the main culprit has to be the data model but is there a way temporarily to actually not show those rows which dont have data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve my issue, I instead right clicked on the column and unticked `show items with no data`

Answer (score 0):

Select your visual, then on the Filter pane on the right hand side, under `Filters on this visual`, add/set a filter condition on `RangedDays` is `not blank`.

Comment: I tried that originally but it still shows the blank row, no matter which measure I use